# What is the shortest and most preferred way of writing the result?

Tags: fractions

Let's say I have to calculate 6/4 (i know, it's simple). Would the preferred answer be 3/2 or 1.5?
Same with square roots: is sqrt(2) a better answer than 2^(1/2)?

Comment: There's really no "better" or "best" way, it's really up to your marking scheme.

Comment: I would prefer $\sqrt 2$. For the shortest, try with a ruler.

Comment: No really best way here. As a hint, if the outcome is an algebraic number, write it down as such and not as a decimal number.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Good one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from @Wuestenfux in comments: 
No really best way here. As a hint, if the outcome is an algebraic number, write it down as such and not as a decimal number